# file I/O with google app engine

Tags: python, html, xml, google-app-engine, datastore

I want to provide a field in my html file so that people can upload their XML files to be imported to the datastore. How can I read and process this file inside the app engine once it is uploaded ? (I dont want to store the file with blobstore. Just want to read, process and throw it away) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `StringIO` when you need a file-like object for use with libraries that act on files. (Although I believe most XML parsers will happily accept a string instead of requiring a file-like object.)